# Sendgrid not working on heroku but working locally

Tags: php, heroku, sendgrid

I just installed the send grid app on my heroku dashboard , followed all the required steps from the documentation to send mails via php SMTP... It works perfectly when tested locally but when I test it on the heroku server is crashes my page and still sends no mail..

What am I doing wrong anybody encountered this before?